# How to Typecast in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, cgfloat

I'm working on a custom path for UIBezierPath, and I'm getting the "Cannot assign a value of type (CGFloat) to a value of type CGFloat." I think it's because there is some issue with typecasting? How can I fix this? The warnings are popping up for the "X = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2)" line and "Y = m1 * X + b1" line.

```
func lineIntersection(m1: CGFloat, b1: CGFloat, m2: CGFloat, b2: CGFloat, inout X: CGFloat, inout Y: CGFloat) -> Bool {
    if m1 == m2 {
    return false
}  else if X = (b2 - b1)/(m1 - m2) {
    return true
} else if Y = m1 * X + b1 {
    return true
    } else {
    return false
    }
}
```

I'll be calling this function in another function later on

```
func xxx() {
        var outX = CGFloat()
        var outY = CGFloat()
        lineIntersection(oldSlope, b1: oldIntercept, m2: newSlope, b2: newIntercept, X: &outX, Y: &outY)
}
```

Comment: Replace `=` with `==` in your `else if` conditions, also in this case no need for inouts. (unless you actually wanted to assign values to X and Y instead of comparing, but your code wouldn't work either for this).

Comment: Are you sure you want `=` on those lines and not `==`?

Comment: You should really use `CGPoint`

Comment: You're probably coming from a C programming background and trying to combine assignment with conditional test. Swift finds this unsafe and doesn't allow it.

Comment: You really need to read at least the introduction to Swift in Apple's books. You are getting basic things totally wrong, and asking questions on Stackoverflow is no replacement for actually learning your trade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Swift doesn't have zero as a "false" value, you need to explicitly compare with `!= 0` in the `if`s. Also, move the assignments to separate lines instead of doing it as part of the condition.
2. Floating point equality comparisons are not reliable except in a few special cases, and this is not likely to be one of them.
3. I would remove the `inout` parameters and return an optional `CGPoint`, i.e., `-> CGPoint?`. Return `nil` for `false`, and the `CGPoint` intersection for `true`.

Resulting function (I've removed the equality checks altogether; the floating point division by zero is not dangerous, we can check for Inf/NaN later):

```
func lineIntersection(m1 m1: CGFloat, b1: CGFloat, m2: CGFloat, b2: CGFloat) -> CGPoint? {
    let x = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2)
    let y = m1 * x + b1
    return y.isFinite ? CGPoint(x: x, y: y) : nil
}
```

Use at the calling location would be something like:

```
if let intersection = lineIntersection(m1: m1, b1: b1, m2: m2, b2: b2) {
    // use intersection.x and intersection.y
}
```

As for the literal question of how to typecast (although this was not the issue here), you can init even "basic types" with something like `CGFloat(value)`, which results in a type *conversion* by "creating" a new `CGFloat` from `value`. Several types also have alternative ways to specify how exactly the conversion happens, e.g., `Int32(truncatingBitPattern: largerInteger)` takes the lowest 32 bits as they are, whereas just `Int32(largerInteger)` would crash if it over- or underflows. Casting as such is done with `as` (known to succeed at compile time), `as?` (try casting at runtime, `nil` on failure), `as!` (try casting at runtime, assert success).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. It was extremely helpful. Much appreciate it